# yum and command line field

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I'm reading the official documentation of Red Hat 6 (Deployment Guide) where in chapter 6 about yum they use the following command to show transactions:

```
yum history info (id)
```

this command should allegedly show the command that has been issued by the user on the command line. However on my Red Hat 6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
) I cannot see that field.

Here's what should appear in the command response according to documentation:

```
Command Line: install screen
```

my yum seem to display all fields but Command Line.

Is the documentation outdated or is it yum version problem?

Here's the output of yum history info 8:

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Transaction ID : 8
Begin time     : Mon Aug 19 13:41:54 2013
Begin rpmdb    : 1084:65de5635b414c70762820c21547fbd04b195ff4b
End time       :            13:42:13 2013 (19 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1084:0199a2a8ec5de1036ccf87f49bd3e091e410cb5f
User           : TR <tr>
Return-Code    : Success
Transaction performed with:
    Installed    rpm-4.8.0-12.el6.i686
    Installed    yum-3.2.27-14.el6.noarch
Packages Altered:
    Updated      tar-2:1.23-3.el6.i686
    Update           2:1.23-11.el6.i686
history info
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try giving the system an entitlement, and updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum history command line is implemented in a later version of yum.

According to [this doc](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumDB), in version [3.2.29-18](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=662243) it is implemented, so I'd go ahead and `yum update yum`

yum rpm package changelog:

```
* Thu Aug 11 2011 James Antill <james.antill@redhat.com> - 3.2.29-18
- Deal with pre scripts errors better.
- Resolves: rhbz#661962
- history nows stores and display rpmdb/yumdb information (Eg. from_repo).
[...]
```

**edit:** yum still won't be able to see the command line information from transactions made before the functionality was implemented.

Comment: I updated yum to 3.2.29-40. Now I get a few more fields in the output, but Command Line field is still not there.

Comment: have you upgraded anything after yum? It won't be  able to find things you downloaded before upgrading yum...

Comment: No, I haven't. It's just a test system.

Comment: OK so 1. update yum to version >= 3.2.29-18. 2. install something else. 3. check yum history info for that id, and the command line should be there. It can't show command line from before the function was implemented

Comment: Yeah! You are right. Indeed it's not able to show the previous commands, but the new one are displayed in Command Line field. Thanks for a hint!